# What are the chances that vegan cocoa butter is adulterated with cow butter?

Tags: food-safety, allergy

I have a severe intolerance to lactose. I took years to learn what kind of food to avoid, but in the past few years I did relatively well. Recently I had a sequence of severe reactions. I am still trying to identify the cause. I suspect that a cocoa butter labelled as vegan and organic that I recently started using is adulterated with cow milk. Is it possible? What are the chances?

It is branded Dragon Super foods.

Comment: There are other far more likely candidates for cross contamination with dairy. Cocoa powder, as one related example, may be packed on the same production line as drinking chocolate, which contains milk powder. Cocoa butter, on the other hand, has no need to go near dairy.

Comment: You might try cutting it out for a while. If your reactions disappear, you will have a pretty good idea that it was the sole contributor.

Comment: "Cow butter" already only contains miniscule amounts of lactose. Even if your cocoa butter were adulterated with it the likelihood of it triggering lactose intolerance effects is almost non-existent.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a weird thing for them to do. Various processed vegetable oils are available with properties more similar to cocoa butter than cow butter’s, and they are cheaper.